# char arrays grouped in one single array

Tags: c

This is my example:

```
char a[LEN_A];
char b[LEN_B];
char c[LEN_C];
char d[LEN_D];
char e[LEN_E];
char f[LEN_F];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LAST_ID; ++i)
{
    char *p = stuff_to_parse;
    string_val[i] = NULL;
    while(p)
    {
        /* Do some parsing stuff*/

        /* Finished parsing ... */
        string_val[i] = p;
        /* Assing value in string_val[i] to a, b, c, .. within this loop */

    }
}
```

How can I assign the values of `string_val[i]` within the loop to the different char arrays `a`, `b`, `c`, ..? I need an array of char arrays, am I right?

Thx for the help!

EDIT:
Q: What determines if it goes to a,b,c,d..

I've an ID list.

```
enum id_t
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    LAST_ID
};
```

Comment: "I need an array of char arrays, am I right?" You tell us, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I've the parsed value stored in string_val[i], within this loop I want to assign the value to a,b,c,d.. using the loop index i.

Comment: What determines whether it goes to a, b, or c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in a constrained environment and it seems you need to allocate everything in the stack, you can simply keep your current design with the several arrays and then create another one with pointers to those for indexing purposes only:

```
char a[LEN_A],  b[LEN_B],  c[LEN_C],  d[LEN_D],  e[LEN_E],  f[LEN_F];
char* stuff[] = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LAST_ID; ++i)
{
    char *p = stuff_to_parse;
    string_val[i] = NULL;
    while(p)
    {
        /* Do some parsing stuff*/

        /* Finished parsing ... */
        string_val[i] = p;
        /* Assing value in string_val[i] to a, b, c, .. within this loop */
        stuff[i] = p;

    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `switch(i)` and in each case use a different array.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of char arrays like this:

```
char x[6][LEN];
```

However, in this case, all char arrays would have the same length. If you need them to have different sizes you need to use dynamic allocation:

```
char* x[6];
x[0] = malloc(LEN_A);
x[1] = malloc(LEN_B);
[...]

// do your stuff

// now clean up
free x[0];
free x[1];
[...]
```

Comment: Or they could still be in the stack and have the array of pointers initialised with pointers to the other arrays.

Comment: But then you would still have to define a to f. If you are dynamically accessing them, you (probably) shouldn't have them as variables.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I can't really use malloc here. Embedded system and no malloc support.